# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Issue Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am working on a rails app with a nested form ect.. Every thing was working well until I added a button to try to add new line items to a form.. The Layout is a user can create a GeneralReport and once inside the GeneralReport they can then add a Report Entry (GenRepEnt) however when i add the button i get the following error.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
> GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController#new
>
> **EDIT # 1** The functionality works in Console and dose as a result populate in the local app..

The Link in question? is

```
    <%= link_to "New Report Entry", new_general_report_gen_rep_ent_path(@gen_rep_ents) %>
```

The Controller for GenRepEnts is as follows:

```
class GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gen_rep_ent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /gen_rep_ents
  # GET /gen_rep_ents.json
  def index
    @gen_rep_ents = GenRepEnt.all
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1
  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/new
  def new
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:general_report_id])
    @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.new
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /gen_rep_ents
  # POST /gen_rep_ents.json
  def create
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:general_report_id])
    @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.new(gen_rep_ent_params)
    @gen_rep_ent.general_report_id = @general_report.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gen_rep_ent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @general_report, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @general_report}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @general_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /gen_rep_ents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gen_rep_ent.update(gen_rep_ent_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gen_rep_ent, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gen_rep_ent }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gen_rep_ent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /gen_rep_ents/1
  # DELETE /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def destroy
    @gen_rep_ent.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gen_rep_ents_url, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gen_rep_ent
      @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gen_rep_ent_params
      params.require(:gen_rep_ent).permit(:time, :report, :general_report)
    end
end
```

My GeneralReport Model:

```
class GeneralReport < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Adds Model Relationships

    ## GeneralReport -> GenRepEnt
    has_many :gen_rep_ents, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My GenRepEnt Model:

```
class GenRepEnt < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :general_report
  
end
```

This is the Routes.rb File:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :general_reports do 
    resources :gen_rep_ents, except: [:index], controller: 'general_reports/gen_rep_ents'
  end
  
end
```

And just incase here is the Rake/Routes for the nested route

```
  general_report_gen_rep_ents POST   /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents(.:format)          general_reports/gen_rep_ents#create
 new_general_report_gen_rep_ent GET    /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/new(.:format)      general_reports/gen_rep_ents#new
edit_general_report_gen_rep_ent GET    /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/:id/edit(.:format) general_reports/gen_rep_ents#edit
     general_report_gen_rep_ent GET    /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/:id(.:format)      general_reports/gen_rep_ents#show
                                PATCH  /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/:id(.:format)      general_reports/gen_rep_ents#update
                                PUT    /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/:id(.:format)      general_reports/gen_rep_ents#update
                                DELETE /general_reports/:general_report_id/gen_rep_ents/:id(.:format)      general_reports/gen_rep_ents#destroy
```

I do apologize if this is a simple issue but it may just be i need a second set of eyes on it as ive been putting some long hours into it.. All help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if more info is needed.

**EDIT # 2**

Server Log Provided:

```
Started GET "/general_reports/%23%3CGenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30%3E/gen_rep_ents/new" for ::1 at 2015-09-10 02:01:04 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"general_report_id"=>"#<GenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30>"}
  GeneralReport Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "general_reports".* FROM "general_reports" WHERE "general_reports"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find GeneralReport with 'id'=#<GenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30>):
  app/controllers/general_reports/gen_rep_ents_controller.rb:17:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (10.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (67.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (46.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (108.5ms)


Started GET "/general_reports/%23%3CGenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30%3E/gen_rep_ents/new" for ::1 at 2015-09-10 02:01:04 -0600
Processing by GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"general_report_id"=>"#<GenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30>"}
  GeneralReport Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "general_reports".* FROM "general_reports" WHERE "general_reports"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find GeneralReport with 'id'=#<GenRepEnt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa547608f30>):
  app/controllers/general_reports/gen_rep_ents_controller.rb:17:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (54.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (43.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (96.0ms)
```

Comment: Please shorten your code, so the people you want help from can see quickly the releavant things for your problem: put in only the used routes, only the relevant actions in the controller

Comment: on the other side, look at the log or console, and copy the params hash that lead to the error.

Comment: Done. I have cut out alot of the fat.. i am used to being asked for more so i figured i would provide all that i was thinking about.. my apologies for making eyes bleed.

Comment: what is wrong with your naming? what is a GenRepEnt ? and i really wonder about  a GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController . never saw such a crazy naming before on SO

Comment: GeneralReport is a General Report GenRepEnt is a General Patrol Entry.. Im working on naming.. First Rails app.. the conventions have gotten much better since this one was made..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new method need to find the parent general report. So the link path need to include the id of the parent object.

So instead of this:

```
 <%= link_to "New Report Entry", new_general_report_gen_rep_ent_path(@gen_rep_ents) %>
```

you need this:

```
 <%= link_to "New Report Entry", new_general_report_gen_rep_ent_path(@general_report) %>
```

Comment: oh wow! that was a tired moment indeed! thank you so much for your quick response and the tips!